# UIWebView: Content get bigger when reload

Tags: ios, uiwebview, contentsize

I'm having problem of UIWebView: I create a webview at the ViewDidLoad, and a button to reload  the page, and everytime I click the webview download a new picture but the height get longer and longer (url gives random picture).

```
//Here is how I create it
pubTop = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 70)];
    [pubTop loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_PUB_LEVEL4]]];
    [pubTop setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    pubTop.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

and I do reload by: [pubTop reload];

I need help please!!!